# How do you reposition a Stratocaster bridge?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge

I recently got a cheap Squier bullet Strat, I did a few mods and upgraded the parts, then I realized when I was putting in new pickups for it, that the bridge is positioned incorrectly so that the high e string goes in the space between the b and e pole pieces. I decided to move the bridge a little bit to the treble side to get the e string on the pole piece by putting in dowels for the old holes and drilling new ones with a drilling jig (I do not have a drill press). Would this work? and are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Could it be that the pole pieces on the new pickup are spaced differently than the originals or the pickup itself is in the wrong position? If you move the bridge the strings may not be centered over the neck. Maybe you can post a pic or 2...

Comment: Does This Strat have a Whammy Bar? This could really  screw things up if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at my own strat and realized that the bridge pickup pole piece also does not line up directly with the E string. That said, I've been quite happy with the way it sounds. This leads me to believe that the folks at Fender may have designed the guitar to work the way it does with a diminished sensitivity on that particular string when it is added into the mix. If it were me, I think I'd try the pickup mounted just the way things are to see how it sounds. Then if you still desire change, you might consider altering how the pickup lines up with the strings.

Comment: You could also install a rail style pickup that doesn't have separate poles.